# Continue the loop once the item meets a condition using a python generator

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, generator

I have a list of random numbers. I want to refine the list so that there is no pair of numbers that has a product of 0.5. I am trying to use the `next` method for python generator so that I can continue the loop as soon as the condition is met. Another reason is that I want to avoid a nested for-loop, so that the code can continue the main loop when the condition is met.

It's worth noting that in my real case the computational cost to check the condition is very expensive, and this is why I want to use a generator, so that I can continue the loop as soon as the condition is met, instead of checking the condition with all current existing numbers in `refined_list`. Here I just use a simple condition `i * j == 0.5` as an example.

Below is my code

```
import random

rands = [random.uniform(0,1) for _ in range(100)]
refined_list = []
for i in rands:
    if refined_list: # Make sure the refined list is not empty
        if next(j for j in refined_list if i * j == 0.5):
            continue
    refined_list.append(i)

print(refined_list)
```

However, I get the `StopIteration` error once the condition is met.

So how should I continue the loop using a generator? Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in `next` it self, either your condition is true, either is raises the exception

---

You may use `any`

```
for i in rands:
    if refined_list:  # Make sure the refined list is not empty
        if any(j for j in refined_list if i * j == 0.5):
            continue
    refined_list.append(i)
```

You could refactor the condition to group the condition, and get

```
for i in rands:
    if not (refined_list and any(j for j in refined_list if i * j == 0.5)):
        refined_list.append(i)
```

Comment: Does ```any``` continue the loop once it finds an item that meets the condition, or does it also check condition with all items like ```all```?

Comment: @shuha918 it stops at first match ;) it uses the benefits of the generator given